# Is there a way to allow an app to use the camera of a supervised device?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apple-profile-manager

I have an Enterprise App with a supervised device.  It is setup in single app mode.  I made a change to the app and pushed it out.  We want to be able to use the camera.  When I select the button to use the camera the view is black.  When I test it on unsupervised devices I can turn the feature on in the privacy settings.

I don't see a feature to allow an app to use the camera in my Profile Manager.  Does anyone know if there is a push setting for this feature? Can you manage the privacy settings in Profile Manager?

Allow use of Camera is checked in the the Restrictions Payload.

Comment: When you say "Allow use of Camera is checked off in the the Restrictions Payload" do you mean that there is *no* check against "Allow use of camera" ? If so, how do you expect your app to be able to use the app when it isn't permitted by the device restrictions?

Comment: There is a visible check in the box to allow the use of the camera.